# JS: traversing DOM tree in specific order?

Tags: javascript

I can make a function that takes a node and goes through each node until I find what I am looking for:

```
function traverseTree(node, results=[]) {
     if (node.children.length) {
         [...node.children].forEach(node => {
             traverseTree(node)
         });
     } else {
         // if node is what I am looking for, then push to result
     }
}
```

is there another way to traverse the DOM in a specific order...like would there be a way to do in order or breadth first search of a DOM tree in this manner?

Comment: Sure, all it takes is writing out the logic

Comment: you might want to consider using the existing [`TreeWalker` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker). See here for an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker#example

Comment: Or rather a [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator), which is much easier to use, and already has the preorder depth-first *tree order*.